# Get loaded component in parent resolver

Tags: angular, router, angular-router, angular-resolver

I'm trying to access the component's name in parent resolver, but it is always `undefined`. It might be a limitation of the angular router, a not implemented feature, or an intentional behaviour, because at that point the component is not identified.

Imagine having a parent resolver. This route has child routes.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    resolve: {
      content: ContentResolver,
    },
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'a',
        component: AComponent,
        data: {
          contentId: 'AContentId',
        },
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
];
```

```js
export class ContentResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {
  constructor() {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log(route.component);
    return of(true);
  }
}
```

When I navigate to route `a` I expect to see `AComponent` as value of `route.component`. It is `undefined`.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dy4duk?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

Comment: Have console.log(route)? what is result?

Comment: Route is an object. This object has a property called component, which is undefined. If you define a resolver next to the route (so not a parent resolver), then the component property is set correctly.

Comment: What is in children? https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Comment: @Vega I updated the OP with a stackblitz link.

Comment: state.root.component always has AppComponent as value. The point is to get the activated child route's component. E.g. you click navigate to 'b', so the component should be BComponent

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, this is surely a childrens problem. You can loop until you dont find your data. Something like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class HeroResolver implements Resolve<HeroService> {
  constructor(private service: HeroService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any>  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      route.children.forEach((children) => {
        if(children.data != {}){
          if(children.data.contentId){ 
            resolve("Something with your data")    
          }
        }
      })
    })    
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not enough, because there could be nested routes, where we want to do something with the activated route's data and also with its parent's data. I'm gonna update the OP with a stackblitz.